# Is return inside function definition is also a expression in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
fun trueOrFalse(exp: Boolean): String { 
  if (exp) return "It's true!" 
  return "It's false"            
}
```

I was reading the "atomic kotlin" book where it says this function contains 2 expression so I just wanted to is function return also expression in kotlin ?

Comment: Yes it is. Is that all you are after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike most programming languages, Kotlin treats `return ...` not as a statement but as an expression.

The type that the compiler infers for such expressions is [`Nothing`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html), which means that the expression never evaluates to anything, and the control flow never continues normally after such an expression (similar to `throw`-expressions).

An example that demonstrates that it's an expression would be:

```kotlin
val x = when (coin) {
    0 -> 123
    1 -> (return 456) as Nothing
    else -> error("unexpected coin value")
}
```

<sup>[(runnable sample)](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS41LjMxIiwiY29kZSI6ImltcG9ydCBrb3RsaW4ucmFuZG9tLipcbmltcG9ydCBrb3RsaW4ubWF0aC4qXG5cbmZ1biBmKCk6IEludCB7XG4gICAgdmFsIGNvaW4gPSBSYW5kb20ubmV4dEludCgpLmFic29sdXRlVmFsdWUgJSAyXG4gICAgdmFsIHggPSB3aGVuIChjb2luKSB7XG4gICAgICAgIDAgLT4gMTIzXG4gICAgICAgIDEgLT4gKHJldHVybiA0NTYpIGFzIE5vdGhpbmdcbiAgICAgICAgZWxzZSAtPiBlcnJvcihcInVuZXhwZWN0ZWQgY29pbiB2YWx1ZVwiKVxuICAgIH1cbiAgICByZXR1cm4geFxufVxuXG5mdW4gbWFpbigpIHtcbiAgICBmb3IgKGkgaW4gMS4uMTApIHtcbiAgICAgICAgcHJpbnRsbihmKCkpXG4gICAgfVxufSIsInBsYXRmb3JtIjoiamF2YSIsImFyZ3MiOiIiLCJqc0NvZGUiOiIifQ==)</sup>

With the type of a `return ...` expression being `Nothing`, it doesn't make a lot of sense to use it as a part of other composite expressions. However, there are cases when it's convenient:

- `val x = if (foo) bar() else return baz()`
- `val x = foo() ?: return bar()`

Fun fact: expressions like `return return return 5` are valid, although they trigger a compiler warning for unreachable code.